# how to use sorted key without changing the origonal list

Tags: python, sorting

Im trying to find a way to sort the list by the sum of value of every character for each name, and so far the best i got is below. I have no idea how to sort the list while preserving it, but the output ends up being the ord numbers. Ive tried to use a copied list and to get the numbers from that list, but then I have no Idea how to use that to sort the original list.

I want to try to most of the code inside the function, so that it works with the other inputs (sum, length, first name, last name).

Relevant code here:

```
def namefunction()

        global namelist

        for i in range(0,len(namelist)):

            namelist[i]=list(namelist[i])

            for x in range(0, len(namelist[i])):

                namelist[i][x]=ord(namelist[i][x])

        return sum

print(*sorted(namelist, key= namefunction()), sep='\n')
```

Full code for reference here (not really necessary to look at)

```
print('You can sort by first name, last name, length, sum, or words .')

keycheck=input("What do you want to sort by? ")

namelist=['John S. Zmile', 'Giorno Giovana',
          'Kakyoin Hanagashi', 'Trilaw Flanger', 'Stephane Locost', 
          'Bobert Hobert', 'Volvo B10BLE', 'Dale Reid', 'Annika Sörenstam', 
          'Cryt Fider', 'Valentine Prinsep', 'Gamrekeli Tony Toreli']

def namefunction():

    if keycheck=="firstname": 

        return   

    elif keycheck=="last name":

        return lambda x:x[x.rfind(' ')+1]

    elif keycheck=="length":

        return len

    elif keycheck=="words":              
 
        return lambda x: -len(x.split()) 

    elif keycheck =="sum":

        global namelist

        for i in range(0,len(namelist)):

            namelist[i]=list(namelist[i])

            for x in range(0, len(namelist[i])):

                namelist[i][x]=ord(namelist[i][x])

        return sum

print(*sorted(namelist, key= namefunction()), sep='\n')
```

Comment: It's not clear what "sum" you are sorting on, but your function doesn't compute any sort of sum given an *element* of the list being sorted. The function isn't supposed to know or care about the list being sorted; it will get a single element as its argument when called.

Comment: The sum Im trying to sort on is a sum of the ord value of each name (so a name "bob bob", Id want to add the sum of ord(b)+ord(o)+ [you get the point]).  Sorry if its obvious (im just starting out), but I genuinely dont understand by what you mean by given an element? from my understanding I'm just supposed to have the function tell the sorted how to sort the list.

Comment: Your key function gets, say `'John S. Zmile'` as an argument. You would return something like `sum(map(ord, 'John S. Zmile'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand, you want to sort a list of strings by the sum of their characters.

```
def value(char):
    """ Return the position of the character in the alphabet. You could replace it by ord."""
    if not char.isalpha():
        return 0
    return ord(char.lower()) - 96


def namefunction():
    
    if keycheck == "firstname":
        return lambda x: x.split()[0]

    elif keycheck == "last name":
        return lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1]

    elif keycheck == "length":
        return len

    elif keycheck == "words":
        return lambda x: len(x.split())

    elif keycheck == "sum":
        return lambda x: sum(map(value, x))


key = namefunction()
print(*sorted(namelist, key=key), sep='\n')
```